# wxPython Drag and Drop files onto image, to add to array

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simple wxPython application with 1 image "Drop files here!" and 2 buttons.

I want the user to be able to drag and drop files onto the top section/image, at which point the image changes and the files are loaded into an array.

That's all I need but I have hit a major roadblock getting the drag and drop to work. Can someone please take a look at my code and figure out how/where to integrate the Drag and drop event? Any help would be great.

[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG6cB.png)

```
import wx

class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        print(filenames)

        image = Image.open(filenames[0])
        image.thumbnail((PhotoMaxSize, PhotoMaxSize))
        image.save('thumbnail.png')
        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath='thumbnail.png')
        return True

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(300, 340), style= wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        #self.widget = widget

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(300, 340), style= wx.CLOSE_BOX)


        panel1 = wx.Panel(self,-1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self,-1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("RED")

        image_file = 'bgimage1.png'
        bmp1 = wx.Image(
            image_file,
            wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        # image's upper left corner anchors at panel
        # coordinates (0, 0)
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(
            self, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
        # show some image details
        str1 = "%s  %dx%d" % (image_file, bmp1.GetWidth(),
                          bmp1.GetHeight())

        # button
        closeButton = wx.Button(self.bitmap1, label='Generate', pos=(30, 280))
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        clearButton = wx.Button(self.bitmap1, label='Clear', pos=(170, 280))
        clearButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)


        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(panel1, 5, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Layout()

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        self.window.updateDisplay(filenames)
        for name in filenames:
            self.window.WriteText(name + "\n")
            print(name)

        return True

    def OnClose(self, e):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Sizer Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the class `DropTarget` back to front with the **init** after the dropfiles. You also need to put the image and buttons on to one of the panels.
See below:

```
import wx

class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        print("Drop Event",filenames)

#        image = Image.open(filenames[0])
#        image.thumbnail((PhotoMaxSize, PhotoMaxSize))
#        image.save('new.png')
#        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath='new.png')
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(300, 340))


        panel1 = wx.Panel(self,-1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self,-1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("RED")

        image_file = 'bgimage1.png'
        bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(panel1, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))

        # button
        closeButton = wx.Button(panel2, -1, label='Generate',pos=(30, 280))
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        clearButton = wx.Button(panel2, -1, label='Clear',pos=(170, 280))
        clearButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        self.file_drop_target = DropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(self.file_drop_target)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(panel1, 0, wx.EXPAND,0)
        box.Add(panel2, 0, wx.EXPAND,0)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Layout()

    def OnClose(self, e):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Sizer Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This may not be what you want to achieve but at least it's a startiing point and the drag and drop works.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! It might be pushing it, but is there a way to send the background image *behind* the buttons? I can just crop the image so its not over them, but it'd be great to have it behind them if possible. No worries if not.

Comment: See http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/ or have the buttons in the image and on `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` use `event.GetPosition()` to see where on the bitmap the user clicked and react appropriately.